# Poisson Distribution and probability

Tags: probability

> An actuary performs a claim frequency study on a group of auto insurance policies. She finds that the probability function of the number of claims per week arising from this set of policies is P(N=n) where n=1,2,3,. Furthermore, she finds that P(N=n) is proportional to the following function:
>
> $$\propto\frac{e^{-2.9} \cdot 2.9^n}{n!} \qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots$$
>
> What is the weekly average number of claims arising from this group of insurance policies?

So far
Since n increase to infinity

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty k\cdot\frac{e^{-2.9} \cdot 2.9^n}{n!}$$

I dont know how to sum this,can some one please help

Answer (score 1):

Except for the case that there are no claims in a given week, the formula $$\Pr[N = n] \propto e^{-2.9} \frac{(2.9)^n}{n!}, \quad n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots,$$ looks a **lot** like a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda = 2.9$.  But since there is zero probability of $N = 0$ claims, then the constant of proportionality must adjust for this.  In particular, if $$\Pr[N = n] = k e^{-2.9} \frac{(2.9)^n}{n!}, \quad n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots,$$ for some constant of proportionality $k$, then we observe that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr[N = n] = k \left( -e^{-2.9} \frac{(2.9)^0}{0!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2.9} \frac{(2.9)^n}{n!} \right) = k (1 - e^{-2.9}).$$  And since we require this to be equal to $1$, the value of $k$ immediately follows.

Note that the random variable $N$ is a **zero-truncated** Poisson.

Comment: thanks,but I was still unable to come up with answer,so I added the question.

Comment: @TheoRobinson 
You wish to find the value of $k$ such that $~k\sum_{n=\color{crimson}1}^\infty \tfrac{2.9^n e^{-2.9}}{n!}=1~$, when you know that since $\tfrac{2.9^n e^{-2.9}}{n!}\mathbf 1_{n\in\{\color{crimson}0,...\}}$ is the probability mass function for a Poisson distribution, then : $~\sum_{n=\color{crimson}0}^\infty \tfrac{2.9^n e^{-2.9}}{n!}=1~$.$$\therefore ~ k(1-e^{-2.9})=1$$

Comment: @TheoRobinson I have given you a very detailed and nearly complete solution to your stated question; Graham Kemp has then explicitly stated the required equation to be solved in the above comment.  If, after all of this, you still cannot answer the question, then it is my opinion that the difficulty you are having here has more to do with comprehension than with computation.

Comment: I found the answer,so what i change it from n=2,3,4,5 how would it change